# Can you use Present Continuous for non-habitual actions with exact time?

Tags: time, present-tense

I'm already aware of the difference between these two sentences:

> I work for this company.
>
> I'm working for this company.

However, I'm not very sure if this is the same for actions with specific time. Let's say I'm on a week-long vacation and I'm going to the same restaurant every evening. Which of the following would be correct?

> I go to this restaurant at 9 PM
>
> I'm going to this restaurant at 9 PM

The "going to at 9 PM" part sounds jarring but I don't see why it would be incorrect.

Comment: If it is a daily/ frequently happening action (here going to the restaurant), it should be "I go to this restaurant at 9 p.m."

Comment: Is this still true if it's expected that I will stop doing the action in the future?
"Let's say I'm on a week-long vacation and I'm going to the same restaurant every evening." from my post sounds perfectly fine and I think it falls into this category.

Comment: Not always. If something is scheduled to happen / not to happen, it can be in continuous tense. E.g. I am leaving for UAE in the first week of next month. I am not leaving for the US as earlier informed." Here, we shouldn't use "Simple Pre." but "Present Continuous" tense